# Backticks preventing simple JOIN query

Tags: sql

I'm just starting out..experimenting with simple queries. In the JOIN query below, the backticks in the FROM clause prevent the query from running - error is "Unrecognized name: employees at [9:5]" Remove the backticks, however, and the query runs just fine. Why is this? Thank you!

```
SELECT
   employees.name AS employee_name,
   employees.role AS employee_role,
   departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    `employees_data.employees`
INNER JOIN 
    employees_data.departments ON
    employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: What happens if you individually backtick-quote ``employees_data`` and ``employees``?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: Is `employees_data` a table or a schema?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using quoted identifiers, you must quote the database and table name separately, thusly:

```
SELECT
   employees.name AS employee_name,
   employees.role AS employee_role,
   departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    `employees_data`.`employees`
INNER JOIN 
    employees_data.departments ON
    employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: This looks like  a useful answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you quote an identifier like `employees_data.employees` that means the whole identifier. `` from `employees_data.employees` ``  quote the `.`. It means "from the *table* employees_data.employees". In contrast to `from employees_data.employees` or `` from `employees_data`.`employees` ``  which means "from the table employees in the schema employees_data".

***Quote the individual identifiers***, `employees_data` and `employees`; the `.` is syntax.

In general, ***don't quote identifiers if you don't have to***. It can introduce other odd behavior. For example, SQL is generally case-insensitive, but quoting identifiers will make it case-sensitive. `employees` will match `employees` or `Employees` or `EMPLOYEES` but `` `employees` `` only matches `employees`.

Also, ***use schema qualifiers consistently***. In your query sometimes you do and sometimes you don't. For example, your `inner join` is confusing. You're joining `employees_data.departments` on `employees` and `departments`. Is `departments` the same as `employees_data.departments`? Is `employees_data.employees` the same as `employees`?

***If they're all in the same schema, don't use schemas***. Fully qualifying your table names unnecessarily artificially restricts your query to only work on that schema; your query will break if the schema name changes.

```
SELECT
   employees.name AS employee_name,
   employees.role AS employee_role,
   departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    employees
INNER JOIN 
    departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

This will query tables in the current schema, regardless of its name.